# ¿Cómo llamar un módulo a otro lugar en una carpeta desde un script?

Tags: python

Tengo un script `interactive.py` qui appelle des modules d'un autre dossier

```
DrQA (donde llamo el script)
    scripts
        pipeline
            interactive.py
    drqa
        pipeline
        retriever
            utils.py
```

`interactive.py` llama por `utils.py`

```
from drqa import pipeline
from drqa.retriever import utils
```

He llamado interactive.py en el archivo raíz

```
mike@mike-thinks:~/Programing/DrQA$ python3.6 scripts/pipeline/interactive.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scripts/pipeline/interactive.py", line 16, in <module>
    from drqa import pipeline
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'drqa'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scripts/pipeline/interactive.py", line 16, in <module>
    from drqa import pipeline
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'drqa'
```

Aqui esta el contenido de la raíz:

```
mike@mike-thinks:~/Programing/DrQA$ ls
data         drqa.egg-info       LICENSE           scripts
data.tar.gz  drqa.tokenizers     PATENTS           setup.py
download.sh  img                 README.md         test.py
drqa         install_corenlp.sh  requirements.txt  venv
```

#### Actualización

El error podría provenir de la instalación durante la instalación por `python setup.py develop`. Intenté con python, python3 y python3.6 y los resultados son differentes

```
(venv) mike@mike-thinks:~/Programing/DrQA$ python3.6 setup.py develop/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py:261: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'python_requires'
  warnings.warn(msg)
running develop
error: can't create or remove files in install directory

The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the
installation directory:

    [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/test-easy-install-15175.write-test'

The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:

    /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/

This directory does not currently exist.  Please create it and try again, or
choose a different installation directory (using the -d or --install-dir
option).
```

Comment: Ya revisaste la escritura? veo `mike@mike-thinks:~/Programing/DrQA$ python3.6 scripts/pipeline/interactive.py` y usas `'drqa'` DrQA != drqa

Comment: @quevedo si DrQA es el nombre de la raíz, drqa es una subcarpeta

Comment: y en el `__init__` de DrQA la referencia a drqa es correcta? No veo otras opciones de momento

Comment: Prueba agregar en `interactive.py` antes de los imports lo siguiente: `import sys;sys.path.append('../../')`

Comment: @quevedo ¿Qué es *la referencia* a drqa? La única referencia que le doy es `from drqa import pipeline`

Comment: @PatricioMoracho Agrego antes de los imports lo siguiente: import sys;sys.path.append('../../') pero siempre me da el error

Comment: Salvo cuando todas las subcarpetas se incluyen por defecto en `__init__.py` se hace referencia explícita a lo que usa el módulo y cómo se configura. Es posible una de dos situaciones: no hay referencia caso en que la sugerencia de @PatricioMoracho es el camino, o te encuentras una referencia con un nombre mistyped lo corriges y asunto resuelto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo primero que hay que tener en cuenta es que **ejecutas el módulo directamente como script**. Esto causa que no se puedan usar imports relativos y que en la práctica no se pueda importar nada que esté por encima del directorio en el que `interactive.py` está situado, a no ser que esté en los directorios donde el intérprete busca los módulos importados (PYTHONPATH).

La solución en este caso (aparte de instalar el paquete) es añadir la ruta de tu directorio padre al PYTHONPATH en `interactive.py` previamente a los *imports*:

```
import inspect
import sys
import os

current = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())))
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "../.."))

from drqa import pipeline
from drqa.retriever import utils
```

Comment: Muchas gracias FJ, ¡me salva de nuevo!
¿Sabrías por qué no lo dijiste? A menos que me equivoque en [instalación](https://github.com/facebookresearch/DrQA#installing-drqa). Admito que tuve problemas para entender todo...

Comment: ¿@Marine1 instalaste el paquete como se indica en el enlace sin errores?. En concreto llevaste a cabo `python setup.py develop`? Esto no instala el paquete en `site-packages` por el argumento `develop` pero crea un enlace simbólico que permite importar como si estuviera en `site-packages`a la vez que puedes editar el contenido del directorio. Si hiciste esto el paquete `drqa` ya debería estar en el PYTHONPATH como cualquier paquete instalado con pip...

Comment: Si, hice `python setup.py develop` y aqui esta el PATH resultante :
`>>> import sys; print(sys.path)
['', '/usr/lib/python36.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.6', '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/home/mike/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']`

Comment: @Marine1 abre una terminal (situada en `/home` o donde sea, pero fuera del directorio  `DrQA`),  inicia el intérprete python `$ python` e importa el paquete con `>>> import drqa`, si la instalación se realizó correctamente el import debe funcionar, si no encuentra el paquete entonces la instalación no se realizó correctamente o no se hizo en el intérprete que usas ahora.

Comment: Hmm, con el intérprete `python` obtengo `ImportError: No module named 'torch'` pero con `python3.6` esta bien. Pero cuando hizo `python3.6 scripts/pipeline/interactive.py` me dice que `No module named 'drqa'`

Comment: Si `python` y `python3.6` apuntan a intérpretes distintos debiste instalar con `python3.6 -m pip install -r requirements.txt` y  `python3.6 setup.py develop`, creo que tienes instaladas unas cosas en un intérprete y otras en otro... Si `python` te da el error de torch es que te falta instalar pytorch pero tienes drqa instalado en este intérprete (torch se importa de hecho en /DrQA/drqa/__init__.py)...

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80133/discussion-between-fjsevilla-and-marine1).